# Linq Group By: remove the Key from the result

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Linq group by is very different from SQL (because it can work on objects and not just tuples) and not so intuitive at the beginning. I would love to write a small function to put it in a Framework like MoreLinq.

#### Sample data

Let's say we have a c# List with an anonymous type or a DataReader with 3 'columns'.

[image]

You can find this sample data [here on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aHbJBP).

#### Grouping for the first column

```
var grouping = from x in flattenedList
                   group x by x.IDMacroTab
                   into grouping_0                     
                   select new 
                   { 
                    IdMacrotab = grouping_0.Key, 
                    Data = (from y in grouping_0
                    select new { IDTab = y.IDTab, IDSlot = y.IDSlot })
                   };
```

#### The result

And that's the result: the table-like data are splitted in new {Key + Data} where the Property Data contains all the columns but the one used in the grouping.

[image]

#### Is it possible to generalize this kind of operation?

var grouping = flattenedList.GroupColumnsBy(s => s.IDMacroTab);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bunch of reflection that would be possible, but it would only be marginally useful for small amounts of data-only objects.

For large amounts, basically copying all the objects might not be good for memory consumption of the app.

For all objects that are not POCOs, it destroys the usefulness of having OOP and objects, because they were just reduced to POCOs.

So instead of making a copy, using memory you that's just redundant and losing functionality, maybe you could just tweak your output layer to present it the way you want it?

Comment: Thanks. It's just for datarereader like objects. But to understand this question, it could be very useful to read my previous 2 questions. Making a copy of some objects takes just a few byte (since the copy of an object is just a 32 bit integer pointing to a memory location). But the lack of readability of some Linq code, which you see from my previous questions and answer, may have a significant impact. The output layer is the next step...